# Consuming REST Service and Response has Java Keyword "native" as one of the variables

Tags: java, keyword

I am trying to create class

```java
package com.spectrum.biller.orderdetails.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TelephoneNumber {
   private String number;
   private String native;
   private String preferred;
}
```

But I am getting error on variable native "syntax error on token, invalid variable declarator" . But, rest service is sending the Response with TelephoneNumber Class . Here is the response.

```js
{
    "telephoneNumber": {
        "number": "string",
        "native": "string",
        "preferred": "string"
    }
}
```

I need to know how I can declare the native keyword as variable in my class.

Thanks
BPradhan

Comment: can you try with @JsonProperty("native") on top of the field name native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jackson as json library you can annotate your fields with
*@JsonProperty*. There you can define the key name that is mapped to your variable.

In your case you could do

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TelephoneNumber {
   @JsonProperty("number")
   private String number;
   @JsonProperty("native")
   private String nativeValue; //or however you want to name it
   @JsonProperty("preferred")
   private String preferred;
}
```

If you do not use jackson your used library probably has something similar.